# How to fail the insert and update operation upon receiving blank data in a query in following scenario?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, triggers

I've written following two triggers on a MySQL table which will get fire before insert and update operations :

```
IF (NEW.full_name = '') THEN SET NEW.full_name = NEW.user_name; END IF
```

Now what I want to do is whenever the if condition gets satisfied then the insert/update operation should get fail.

The statement

```
THEN SET NEW.full_name = NEW.user_name;
```

should not get execute.

How should I achieve this? Please someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Marc B : That scenario is different. I want answer for my situation. Please don't relate my question to some other question.

Comment: doesn't matter what your scenario is. the situation is the same: you need to abort a trigger, and that question/answer shows you how.